# how to tell Python disutils.core setup function to install under a different root?

Tags: python, distutils

I have this Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
MOD = 'sysinfo'
setup(
    name=MOD, 
    ext_modules=[
        Extension(
            MOD, 
            sources=['python_module.c']
        )
    ]
)
```

When I run it, I get:

```
$./setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sysinfo.so -> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
error: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sysinfo.so: Permission denied
```

Naturally - I don't want and have permissions to, write to `/usr` directory.  I want instead, to install to a different directory, under which I have a linux directory structure. Say, I want to install to `/home/mark/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages`.

I studied `distutils.core` documentation, and used `--help` but could not find any option to install under a different root.

How to do it?

Comment: Shouldn't you setup a virtualenv for this? Or is that not what you're looking for

Comment: @ycx  I don't think so. I don't have root privileges to install virtualenv and I would not want to install some different Python distro. I just don't like that the `setup` function install by default to a system directory and I don't see how to change that to install to my own custom directory.

Answer (score 2):

`./setup.py install` installs the package into global `site-packages/` in your python installation making it available for all users of the system.

`./setup.py install --user` installs the package into local `site-packages/` in your home (`~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/`) making it available only for you.

```
./setup.py install --root ~/custom/directory/
```

installs into `~/custom/directory/usr/lib64/pythonX.Y/site-packages/`.

Comment: Thank you!  But is there a way to install into any custom directory: `~/custom/directory/usr/lib64/pythonX.Y/site-packages/`

Comment: `./setup.py install --root ~/custom/directory/` or `./setup.py install --prefix ~/custom/directory/usr/lib64/`. But then you have to include `~/custom/directory/usr/lib64/bin/` in `PATH` and `~/custom/directory/usr/lib64/` in `PYTHONPATH` and this means you emulate `virtualenv`. IMO it'd be better to `pip install --user virtualenv` and use `virtualenv`.

Comment: Thank you - `--root` worked !  But I don't understand, why is this option not documented anywhere??  I tried to grok the Py code for distutils.core but it was taking too much time and I still did not find anything like the `--root` option.  Please make it an answer and I will accept.  No I don't have to include anything in PATH env variables - I do not need to use that python installation - I just have to install there, like I said in the question.  Maybe distutils.core setup is not the right fit in my case, but somebody else used it and I don't want to change the code too much.

Comment: What do you mean *this option is not documented anywhere*? It certainly is. Run `python setup.py install --help | grep root`.

Comment: OK here is what I do as a programmer, I have done a lot of Py programming, but I guess I am not a guru.  I run `python setup.py`, it fails, I look inside the code for `setup.py`, I see the usage of `distutils.core setup` function, which fails, I look at the documentation for that, there is no mention of any `root` option.  To run the whole script with `--help` never crosses my mind - because apparently, there is nothing in the code that indicates (to a non-guru) that any such option is even available.

Comment: there is some object-oriented magic in there that `setup` function looks at options given to a calling script. Great, but I have never seen that, and I guarantee you 90% of programmers in non-Python-specific companies have never seen such a thing.

Comment: Running `xxx --help` is the second thing a programmer does with a new program; the first one is [reading the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html?highlight=--help). It's Python's magic but not object-oriented. `setup()` accepts keywords arguments in the form [`**kw`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f0af4c54e32d963e1ccbac005bcbcab1913e051f/Lib/distutils/core.py#L57).

Comment: I agree. But `setup.py` is not a "new program", it is a short wrapper script that all it does is call one function `setup`.